# PHP: How to delete every array entry if the index is higher than n?

Tags: php, arrays, indexing, selector

Following problem:
I got an array of objects. It looks like:

```
array(3) {
  [9041]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(0) ""
  }
  [0]=>
  array(1) {
    [9802]=>
    array(2) {
      [2614]=>
      array(6) {
      ...
      }
      [2354]=>
      array(6) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
  [1]=>
  array(1) {
    [9803]=>
    array(1) {
      [8961]=>
      array(6) {
        ...
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I don't need the entries with that high indexes anymore. Is there a way to delete them? I dont know how to filter them? I failed trying it with a for loop. I can access the entry if i know the id ($my_array[9041]), but how to filter for indexes (indexes>n)? If I would knew it I could easily unset the entry. Anyone knows a php method or function for it?

Comment: Are these from a database? Why don't you just query them with ID < n?

Comment: It's complicated. I created that array out of two merged jsons. So the solution of Timesplinter works best for me ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
foreach(array_keys($yourArray) as $index) {
    if($index > 9999)
        unset($yourArray[$index]);
}
```

where `9999` is your highest index you want to keep.

If you want it to work for multidimensional arrays make a recursive function of that.

Comment: Perfect! It worked! Array_keys was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you! :)